# Turn on/off PHP making superglobal array elements available as global variables

Tags: php, superglobals

`$_SESSION['myvar']` becomes available as `$myvar` after a `session_start()` call.
`$_POST['myvar']` becomes available as `$myvar` after a form is posted.

I find the above behavior with the PHP installation/configuration on one server, but not on another server.  How do I query whether the server is configured as such, and how do I configure the installation to change this behavior?  I just can't find anything about this in php.net or elsewhere.

Comment: What PHP versions are you using?

Comment: The installation with register_globals on is PHP version 5.2.  The installation with register_globals off is PHP version 5.6.  So this makes sense.  It gets tricky when developing a replacement website.  Old website depends on old behavior, new website depends on new behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be turned on via `register_globals` in your `php.ini` file. However this is **deprecated** as of 5.3. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals).

> **Warning** This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED
>   as of PHP 5.4.0.